# check my unix account quota

Tags: unix, quota

I have an account on my university's Unix server, but I don't know my quota. How can I check it from the command line??

I tried `quota` but seems not work.

Comment: Which OS does the server run? You said unix but that is about as generic as windows (which could be windows 2, 3.1, 3.11, 95, 98, ... all the way up to win 8 preview)

Answer (score 1):

Give these a shot:

```
quote -v

du -ak | more

ls -l | more
```

(The last one is a more generic method)

Comment: I think the first one should be `quota` not `quote`. Also try `du -hs *` - it will return the full (recursive) size of all the folders (and files) in the current directory.